# How to PixelSearch() faster?

Tags: autoit

Using [`PixelSearch()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/PixelSearch.htm) and relative mouse movement I made this script lock the mouse cursor onto a color :

```
While 1 
    $pos = MouseGetPos()
    $coord = PixelSearch($pos[0]+80, $pos[1]+80, $pos[0]-80, $pos[1]-80, $color, 10,5)
    If IsArray($coord) = 1 Then
        Local $iX = $pos[0], $iY = $pos[1]
        If ($iX < $coord[0]) Then _MouseMoveRelative(1, 0);$iStepSize
        If ($iX > $coord[0]) Then  _MouseMoveRelative(-1, 0);$iStepSize
        If ($iY < $coord[1]) Then  _MouseMoveRelative(0, 1);$iStepSize
        If ($iY > $coord[1]) Then  _MouseMoveRelatsdive(0, -1);$iStepSize
        GUISetState()
    EndIf
WEnd
```

If I increase the steps it's faster, but it moves off target. If I decrease, it's slower but more accurate. How to make this as fast as possible?

Answer (score 1):

> This would be the fastest way because the mouse will move instantly

```
While 1 
    $pos = MouseGetPos()
    $coord = PixelSearch( $pos[0]-40, $pos[1]+40, $pos[0]+40, $pos[1]-40, $color, 10,5 )
    If IsArray($coord) = 1 Then
        Local $iX = $pos[0], $iY = $pos[1]
        If ($iX <> $coord[0]) Then _MouseMoveRelative($coord[0] - $iX,0)
        If ($iY <> $coord[1]) Then  _MouseMoveRelative(0,$coord[1] - $iY)
            ; GUISetState() This shouldn't be inside of a loop.
    EndIf
Wend
```

> If you still want to have a $iStepSize, do it like this:

```
While 1
    $pos = MouseGetPos()
    $coord = PixelSearch( $pos[0]-40, $pos[1]+40, $pos[0]+40, $pos[1]-40, $color, 10,5 )
    If IsArray($coord) = 1 Then
        Local $iX = $pos[0], $iY = $pos[1]
        Local $iXOffset = $coord[0] - $iX, $iYOffset = $coord[1] - $iY

        ToolTip( $coord[0] & " : " & $iX  & @CRLF & $coord[1] & " : " & $iY, $iX, $iY)

        If $iXOffset Then
            If Abs($iXOffset) < $iStepSize Then
                $iMoving = $iXOffset
            Else
                $iMoving = $iStepSize
                If ($iXOffset) < 0 Then $iMoving *= -1
            EndIf
            _MouseMoveRelative($iMoving, 0)

        EndIf


        If $iYOffset Then
            If Abs($iYOffset) < $iStepSize Then
                $iMoving = $iYOffset
            Else
                $iMoving = $iStepSize
                If ($iYOffset) < 0 Then $iMoving *= -1
            EndIf
            _MouseMoveRelative(0, $iMoving)

        EndIf

    EndIf
Wend
```

Comment: This script is untested. Its just a concept. Learn from it and you will surely fix it. :)

Comment: Just increase the step and it will be faster. If you increase the step to a very high number , it will do it instantly just like the first example.

Comment: it's for first person and it skips by alot if i increase the step

Comment: Working exactly as the first one, just remove that tooltip. it may make your screen flash